# clock_gettime() works well on PC but on a server it aborts compilation

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, pthreads

I used the following function to get the execution time of a multi-threaded  program:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&start);
/*
******PROGRAM CODE*************
*/

clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&end);
```

It worked fine on my PC laptop running ubuntu 14.04, but when I try to compile and run it on a server it failed compilation giving an error.

On my PC laptop:

```
laksith@laksithPC:~/Desktop/test$ gcc main_v8.c -lpthread
laksith@laksithPC:~/Desktop/test$ ./a.out
```

On the server:

```
[laksith@gca test_run]$ gcc main_v8.c -lpthread
/tmp/ccyMMmx.o:In function 'main':
main_v8.c:(.text+0x21):undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
main_v8.c:(.text+0x182):undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: OT: You probably better use `-pthread` to compile and link than just telling the linker to link the PThread library by specifying `-lpthread`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a link error - you need to link `librt` - change:

```
gcc main_v8.c -lpthread
```

to:

```
gcc -Wall main_v8.c -lpthread -lrt
```

Note that this is covered in the [Linux man page for `clock_gettime`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime):

> NAME
>         `clock_getres`, `clock_gettime`, `clock_settime` - clock and time functions
>
> SYNOPSIS
>         `#include <time.h>`
>
> ```
>   int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);
>
>   int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);
>
>   int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp);
> ```
>
> Link with -lrt.

Note that newer versions of `glibc` (>= 2.17) no longer have the requirement for linking with `librt`, which probably explains why you didn't need to add `-lrt` for the Ubuntu 14 build on your PC.

Comment: Upvote for explaining why there were no errors in first case

Answer (score 2):

from manual page

```
man -a clock_gettime
```

> CLOCK_GETRES(2)            Linux Programmer’s Manual
>   CLOCK_GETRES(2)
>
> NAME
>          clock_getres, clock_gettime, clock_settime - clock and time functions
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          #include
>
> ```
>    int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);
>
>    int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);
>
>    int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp);
>
>    Link with -lrt.
> ```
>
> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    clock_getres(), clock_gettime(), clock_settime(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
> ```

**Link with -lrt.**